# JQuery :not selector being ignored?

Tags: jquery

Don't know if I'm using the not selector incorrectly but I want everything clicked on to do something apart from the id in the not selector.

Neither of these have worked, I get an alert when the logo is clicked:

```
$('body').not('#logo').click(function(){ 
alert('hi');
});

$('body:not(#logo)').click(function(){ 
alert('hi');
});
```

And the html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('body').not('#logo').click(function(){ 
    alert('hi');
    });

    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div style='width:900px; margin:0 auto; background-color:red; height:600px;'>
    <div id='logo' style='background-color:black; width:200px; height:200px;'>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You are binding the `click` event to `body` elements with `id` attribute different to `#logo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alexander's description of what your code is doing is correct.  You are matching `<body>` elements which do not have an `id` of `logo`.  Since you have only one body tag and it does not have an id of logo, your selector selects your body tag.

One way of doing what you are trying to do would be to attach a handler to the body but then prevent event bubbling on the logo.  That would look something like this:

```
$('body').click(function(){ 
  alert('hi');
});

$("#logo").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJyaA/1/